# symbols not loaded - VS 2012

Tags: vb.net

I am using Professional 2012 version of Visual Studio, Windows 7.  One day, everything was working properly.   The next, I was no longer able to debug because symbols are not being loaded.  This is across all projects.  I have done an exhaustive search on the Internet and this seems to have been a frequent occurrence for people over several years and versions of Visual Studio.    I have tried all of the following, based on suggestions I have seen in my research.   Some of them worked for some of the people being helped.   Some did not.  None have worked for me.

My Build output path is ‘bin\debug\’

In the Advanced Compiler settings, Generate Debug Info is set to FULL and optimizations are not enabled.    Generate Serialization Assemblies is set to AUTO.

I have cleaned and rebuilt my project

I am working in the Debug configuration

I have deleted the BIN and OBJ folders and cleaned and rebuilt my project

My modules view defaults to Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code.  I also tried the Automatically determine the type of code to debug setting.   Neither fixed my problem.

I have run Visual Studio as administrator.   It does not change the behavior.

I have tried loading the symbols from manually from the MODULES form under the DEBUG menu.   I get a dialog saying “A matching symbol file was not found in this folder”.   I selected the file in the folder  to which the window defaulted.   I can see the file.   I have deleted the BIN and watched the PDB file be recreated when I build and run my project.  The file is there.  Something about it is preventing it from being used.

I do not have ‘Enable Just My Code’ checked as a Debugging option.   I have tried checking this also, but it did not help.

I do not have ‘Enable .NET Framework source stepping’ checked as a debugging option.   I have tried this but it did not help.

I am not new to VB, but for this, I am in over my head and I’m desperate.   Can anyone help me fix this.  Thank you!

Comment: There are a *lot* of false alarms for this issue.  You have to document your question better to get help.  Start your program with Debug > Step Into.  You'll get the "Source not available" page, that's normal for a VB.NET program.  Then use Debug > Windows > Modules, locate the assembly that you want to get debug info for and whose Symbol Status column shows "Symbols not loaded"..  Right click it > Symbol Load Information.  Show us what you see.

Comment: I do not know how to paste a picture into this editor.   However, what I'm seeing is 'Cannot find or open the PDB file.'.

Comment: I do not know how to paste a picture into this editor.   However, what I'm seeing is 'Cannot find or open the PDB file.'.     

When I have tried to LOAD the labels I'm prompted to navigate to the location of the PDB file and the PDB file is defaulted in this dialog  When I select it, however, it tells me "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder".   I have deleted the BIN and OBJ folders and cleaned and rebuilt my project.  I can see that the PDB file is recreated.  Is there more to do that I am missing?

Thank you for following up!